# Search DataTable by column for a specific row

Tags: c#, performance, .net-datatable

I would like to know if there are ways to make this run faster. Not a big concern right now, but I would like to think long term, it might be important.

This is C#, and I can not change the input parameters data types, but basically I have to make something like the SQL: `SELECT returnCol FROM dt WHERE ColName = ColValue`

As the datatable itself: it has more than 100 columns, but it should not too many rows, usually ~10 rows but it can spike up to 100 rows sometimes. This is part of a data parse that is happening once a minute, that is why I am trying to see if there are ways for enhancement.

```
private string FindInT(DataTable dt, string ColName, string ColValue, string returnCol)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (row[ColName].ToString().ToLower().Trim() == ColValue.ToLower().Trim())
                {
                    return row[returnCol].ToString();
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing to worry about. With only 10 rows and 100 columns you will not even be able to measure the difference with a profiler.

Comment: *it might be important*, but it might well not be. I wouldn't worry, as @t3chb0t said you're dealing with a tiny data set: before the performance of this becomes the bottleneck, there are probably other parts of your code that will need to be revisited. The alternatives (rewriting it with LINQ, using a `RowFilter` on `DataView`, or calling `DataTable.Select()`) are likely to be slower - but don't take my word for it: benchmark. This sounds like a case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

1. Trim `ColValue` once rather than every iteration through the loop.
2. Use a case-insensitive string compare rather than performing `.ToLower()` on two different strings on every loop iteration.

Result:

```
private string FindInT(DataTable dt, string ColName, string ColValue, string returnCol)
{
    ColValue = ColValue.Trim();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (string.Equals(
            row[ColName].ToString().Trim(),
            ColValue,
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return row[returnCol].ToString();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Why the `Cast<DataRow>()` method call? Why not just `foreach` over the Rows property of the DataTable?

Comment: @GregBurghardt you found a victim of my copy/pasting. It can and will go away.